# How to avoid "show all content" msg on HTTPS site in IE9?

Tags: https, show

We have an a HTTPS site that brings up a page from a different site of ours that’s HTTP.

In IE (9), we get the message at the bottom of the page:
“Only secure content is displayed. What’s the risk? [Show all content]”.

When the button is clicked, it closes the lightbox-ish control that's open and returns to the page it was overlaid on.

Does anyone know how to avoid this?

In the HTTP site’s page, one guy here had the idea to add, at the end of On_Load, the following to turn off cross-site scripting protection:
    this.Response.Headers.Add("X-XSS-Protection", "0");

Both sites are C# / ASP.NET 4.0.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the other site not available via https? That warning's there for a reason...

Comment: Ack, I was expecting a notification email, so I didn't know you answered (for which, thanks).  In the cs code it is going to an https url for the site, "https://secure.oursite.com" instead of the usual public-accessible "http://oursite.com".

Answer (score 0):

Add the url to your trusted sites, it's the only way if you don't send all data through https.
Internet Options -> Security -> Trusted Sites -> Sites.
If this is something that needs to be company wide, I would recommend pushing out the rule via a group policy.

Alternatively, allow access the control using https on the other site (if you can) and reference that - the warning will disappear.

Comment: I was expecting a notification email if someone answered, so I just noticed your response; thanks.
In the cs code it is going to an https url for the site, "secure.oursite.com"; instead of the usual public-accessible "oursite.com".

Comment: I was expecting a notification email if someone answered, so I just noticed your response; thanks.
In the cs code it is going to an https url for the site, "https://secure.oursite.com"; instead of the usual public-accessible "http://www.oursite.com".

Comment: Hmmm, adding those sites to the IE trusted list didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The real setting to enable here is to "Display mixed content" for the zone of the site you want.  If the site is on your Intranet, you select Intranet zone in the Security settings, then Custom level.  If it's an Internet site, you go there and go to Custom level.

There, you should see the "Display mixed content" setting, and simply select "Enable", then "OK" your way out of the dialogs.

**Reference:**  https://www.mydigitallife.net/how-to-disable-only-secure-content-is-displayed-in-ie-always-show-all-mixed-content/